# Change name of a Pointer to function automatically

Tags: c++, pointers

I would like to automatically change the name of a pointer to a function, in this case the name of the pointer to function "CImageGraph", as shown below. For instance I would like the pointer name to be "pGraph" plus the loop index "ttt"; However, I am getting errors. So what is the best way to change the name of a pointer automatically? Thanks.

```
const word nStates      = 9; 
const int T             = 6; 
const int nState        = 2; 
for(int ccc = 0; ccc < nStates; ccc++){
    for(int ttt = 0; ttt < T; ttt++){
        string pGraph = "pGraph"+ttt;
        CImageGraph *pGraph = new CImageGraph(nState);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no (direct) way. ... What is the real purpose of this XY-problem? I´m sure there´s a better solution [than a map etc.].

Comment: So you saying you have pointer to function `A`, and you want to make it a pointer function `A1`?

Comment: No. I am actually interested in changing the name of the pointer itself automatically not the function it is pointing  i.e. I want to create pointer names using the index as: pGraph0, pGraph1, pGraph2, pGraph3, pGraph4, pGraph5 and pGraph6 all pointing to CImageGraph function in different addresses.

Comment: That's simply not possible. Use an array or a map.

Comment: You can't. Have you thought about e.g. [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)? Maybe even a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)?

Comment: @Joachim Could kindly give me an example using std:::map.. I am still new to C++. Thanks.

Comment: I'm asking you again, what do you want to achieve? ... If you´re certain a map is a good solution, please use Google or the site search here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to find a solution using arrays, thanks for the hints. The solution is as below:

```
const word nStates      = 9; 
const int T             = 6; 
const int nState        = 2; 
for(int ccc = 0; ccc < nStates; ccc++){
CImageGraph **pGraph = new CImageGraph*[T];
    for(int ttt = 0; ttt < T; ttt++){
        pGraph[ttt] =  new CImageGraph(nState);
        //Other processes
    }
}
```